# Why am I getting this bizarre 'You must add a reference to assembly' error?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, constructor, reference

Here's a very simple problem for you all. I have a view model class with a constructor, so far, so good:

```
public DigitalServiceProviderPriceViewModel(Release relatedRelease)
{
    this.relatedRelease = relatedRelease;
    InitialiseViewModel(new TracksModel(StateManager.CurrentUser));
    InitialiseDigitalServiceProviderPrice();
}
```

This is in a ViewModels dll and is called from the code behind of a `UserControl` class:

```
DigitalServiceProviderPriceViewModel digitalServiceProviderPriceViewModel = 
    new DigitalServiceProviderPriceViewModel(viewModel.Release);
```

This all works just fine, but I needed to add another input parameter to the constructor, so I did this:

```
public DigitalServiceProviderPriceViewModel(Release relatedRelease, 
    DspProductTypes dspProductType)
{
    this.relatedRelease = relatedRelease;
    DspProductType = dspProductType;
    InitialiseViewModel(new TracksModel(StateManager.CurrentUser));
    InitialiseDigitalServiceProviderPrice();
}
```

And then called it like this:

```
DigitalServiceProviderPriceViewModel digitalServiceProviderPriceViewModel = new 
    DigitalServiceProviderPriceViewModel(viewModel.Release, DspProductTypes.None);
```

However, after doing this, I get this error:

> **Error    3   The type 'Midas.Models.Interfaces.ITracksModel' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Midas.Models, Version=3.1.5168.25362, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=fd8cb4d036a0621f'.    C:\DevelopmentProjects\Midas\Midas.Views\ReleaseView.xaml.cs    49  13  Midas.Views**

The `ITracksModel` instance is an input parameter for the `InitialiseViewModel` method... you can see a `TracksModel` object being passed through in the original example. However, I didn't require a reference to the `Models` dll when using the previous constructor, so I experimented... even if I change the new constructor to this, I still get the same error:

```
public DigitalServiceProviderPriceViewModel(Release relatedRelease, int number)
{
    // Just plain int input parameter and no content in constructor
}

...

DigitalServiceProviderPriceViewModel digitalServiceProviderPriceViewModel = new 
    DigitalServiceProviderPriceViewModel(viewModel.Release, 0);
```

Clearly, I can't add a reference to the `Models` dll from the `Views` dll as there is already one to the `ViewModels` dll which *does* reference the `Models` dll. Also, I should *not* have to, as the program had been built and run successfully every time up until this point.

So, can anyone shed some light onto this problem? **Why do I get an error when simply adding one new input parameter to the constructor? Finally, how do I get rid of this error?**

---

UPDATE >>>

I Just thought that I'd mention that it would be easy to fix this issue by avoiding it altogether and not using the constructor to pass these values, but I'm trying to find out what is going on here, rather than trying to find a way around it.

Comment: Have you tried Clean Solution and ReBuild?

Comment: Does your `DspProductTypes` class have a public member with a return value or parameter of type `ITracksModel`? That would seem the most likely issue...

Comment: With respect @LucasAbilidebob, I'm not even going to answer that comment... I am *not* a noob.

Comment: `DspProductTypes` is an `enum`, nothing more, but look at the last example... it doesn't even matter what type the second parameter is... it still breaks.